# How to use CIFilter sunbeamsGenerator in Swift 5 and iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

Please, could someone to provide me an example code for `CIFilter` sunbeamsGenerator in Swift 5 and iOS 13?

I am trying to create an extension to apply this filter and I have this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputImage.'

The code works ok for the Blur filter but not for the sunbeamsGenerator

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

public extension UIImage {

public func withBlurFilter() -> UIImage {
       let ciImage = CIImage(image: self)!
       let filter = CIFilter.gaussianBlur()
       filter.inputImage = ciImage
       filter.radius = 30
       let vintage = ciImage.applyingFilter(filter.name)
       return vintage.uiImage()
   }

    public func withSunFilter() -> UIImage {
        let ciImage = CIImage(image: self)!
        let filter = CIFilter.sunbeamsGenerator()
        let sunbeam = ciImage.applyingFilter(filter.name)
        return sunbeam.uiImage()
    }

}
```

Thanks on advance, I am new in CoreImage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CISunbeamsGenerator` doesn't need an input image – it will generate a sunbeam effect (hence the name) that you can use to, for instance, blend over another image.

When you call `ciImage.applyingFilter(...)` it will try to assign the image as `inputImage` to the given filter. But generators don't have that property, hence the error.

You can do something like this instead:

```
public func withSunFilter() -> UIImage {
    let ciImage = CIImage(image: self)!
    let filter = CIFilter.sunbeamsGenerator()
    let sunbeam = filter.outputImage!
    let output = sunbeam.composited(over: ciImage)
    return output.uiImage
}
```

Check the [parameters of `CISumbeamsGenerator`](https://cifilter.io/CISunbeamsGenerator/) to see what you can do with it.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I checked, I modified and I set some defaults. But I tried all the options and I always get the same error. I tried this params configuration by default:  let params: [String: Any] = [
            "inputCenter": CIVector(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150)),
            "inputColor": CIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1),
            "inputSunRadius": 40,
            "inputMaxStriationRadius": 2.58,
            "inputStriationStrength": 0.5,
            "inputStriationContrast": 1.375,
            "inputTime": 0
        ]

Comment: Hmm... really the same error (with `inputImage`)? This is strange since you are not setting it when you don't use `applyingFilter()`.

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much for your great help!